# How to open static YAML files in the browser instead of downloading? (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, yaml

I have Flask app with a static folder that contains `.txt`, `.json`, and `.yml` files:

```
├─ static/
│  ├─ file.txt
│  ├─ file.json
│  └─ file.yml
└─ app.py
```

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I point my browser to http://localhost:5000/static/file.txt or http://localhost:5000/static/file.json, the file renders a preview in the browser. However when I try http://localhost:5000/static/file.yml, downloads the file instead.

How can I open the `.yml` file in the browser like `.txt` and `.json`? I've found that there is a `Content-Disposition` response header which controls this behavior but I'm not sure how this works with resources inside the `static/` folder.

Comment: Are you sure the file extension has to be `.yml`? Why not use `.jsn`? For close to **15** years the [officially recommended extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files has been `.yaml`. You can render the YAML file as text, but it is more likely your **browser** has been set up to display the `.json` extension 'in the browser' and how to do that for `.yaml` depends on your browser.

Comment: @Anthon thanks for your reply. `.yml` and `.yaml` file extensions behave the same way. I've tried four different browsers and all of them are forcing me to download the file. There is a setting in Chrome to "always open this type of file" but this doesn't open _in the browser_, it just downloads the file and then opens in a text editor. Step 1 on [this page](https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/pubapis_openapi_activity) links to a YAML file which opens in the browser which is why I believed this to be a server issue, not a browser issue.